# issue with Open Graph possibly caused by .htaccess Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-social-plugins

Despite many topics on Open Graph, i cant seem to find anything that covers my specific problem.
I have built a site for a client which consists of a number of static html pages. since completion the client wanted social buttons added and so i have inserted all of the necessary Open Graph protocol meta tags.(see below)

```
<meta property="og:title" content="site name" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/page" />
<meta property="og:image"   content="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/images/image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="page description" />
```

When testing a selected page on the Facebook Object debugger, my included meta tags don't seem to be recognised. I think the problem could be caused by the .htaccess file i have included to remove the need for the '.html' and '.php' ...see below; I believe this is the problem as when i test my site witht he .html it seems to work just fine (so long as .html is included in the "og:url" meta tag.) but if not, all kinds of problems occur, and the description Facebook pulls up is actually the text from my css file..?

```
<Files .htaccess> 
order allow,deny 
deny from all 
</Files> 

ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html

Options +MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.co.uk) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

There may be something simple im missing here but it seems to be getting the better of me. Any help would be amazing! Thanks in advance.